# What is SO's duplicate search algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, duplicates

I have a list of ~1200 "unique" strings (I'll call them "categories"), each of which is tied to a list of 5-30(ish) more strings (I'll call these "items").  These have been entered by hand for the last 15 years or so, and now we're trying to get the information into a reusable "library" of categories with lists of items.  Someone is going to have to clean up this library by hand, but I would like to give them some help.

I would like to be able to present likely duplicates for both categories and items to the user, but I'm not sure how to define "likely duplicate".  Most fuzzy search algorithms seem to assume that words might be spelled incorrectly, or synonyms or homonyms might be used, but in my case, it is more likely that the same words are just in a different order, or some words were added one year for legal reasons.

I want to be able to give them a list like:

```
The fox jumped
The quick fox jumped over a log
A quick brown fox jumped over a mushroom-covered log
A log sits where a fox jumped over it
```

It's pretty unlikely that they used synonyms, and extremely unlikely that a word is spelled incorrectly, but it's very likely that terms are out of order.

SO's "Similar Questions" algorithm seems to do this, and it seems to do it much more quickly and efficiently than the "dumb" algorithm that I can think of.  Can anyone tell me how?  I'll be implementing it in C#, with the data stored in SQL Server, so if there's just something out there I can use, I'd be grateful for that info too.